# Common elements in two lists preserving duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, intersection

The goal is to find common elements in two lists while **preserving duplicates**.

For example,

Input:

```
a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]
```

Expected output:

```
[3,5,5]
```

I tried `set.intersection` but set operatons would eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Why is 5 repeated twice in output ?

Comment: Does the order of the output elements matter? Would `[5,3,5]` be okay?

Comment: 5 repeated twice in output because 5 repeated twice in both lists a and b.

Comment: The order of the output elements doesn't matter. [5,3,5] is okay.

Comment: What about 3 ? Two in `a` but only one in `b`

Comment: @ChristophePeter so only one 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
from collections import Counter
ac=Counter(a)
bc=Counter(b)

res=[]

for i in set(a).intersection(set(b)):
    res.extend([i] * min(bc[i], ac[i]))

>>> print(res)
[3, 5, 5]
```

Comment: By my count this performs four passes over the input: one for the two `Counter`s, one for the two `set`s, one to build the `intersection()`, and one for the loop over the intersection. Can some of them be combined, you think?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Sure they can, but sometimes I prefer clearness and simplicity, especially if no issues regarding efficiency are mentioned. It can be done iven in one liner but it will be very ugly and unreadable

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]


def findout(a, b):
    a = a.copy()
    output = []
    for i in b:
        if i in a:
            a.remove(i)
            output.append(i)
    return output


result = findout(a, b)
print(result) # [3, 5, 5]
```

may work.

Comment: Note that this doesn't scale well when the lists are large. It's O(len(a)*len(b)) while the optimal solution is O(len(a)+len(b)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Counter of your lists and use those keys that occure in both and the minimal amount of their values:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]

ca = Counter(a)
cb = Counter(b)


result = [a for b in ([key] * min(ca[key], cb[key])
                      for key in ca
                      if key in cb) for a in b]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[3,5,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Counter` from `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]

ans = []
a_count = Counter(a)
b_count = Counter(b)


for i in a_count:
    if i in b_count:
        ans.extend([i]*min(a_count[i], b_count[i]))

print(ans)
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends if the lists are always sorted like in your example. If so, you can do a cursor approach where

```py
index_a = 0
index_b = 0
common_elements = []

while index_a < len(a) and index_b < len(b):
    if a[index_a] < b[index_b]:
        # then a should check the next number, b should stay
        index_a += 1
    elif a[index_a] > b[index_b]:
        # then the reverse
        index_b += 1
    else:
        # they are equal
        common_elements.append(a[index_a])
        index_a += 1
        index_b += 1
```

However, if they are not sorted like that you're better off maybe doing the set intersection and then turning it back into a list and then for each element add duplicates to equal `min(a.count(el), b.count(el))`?

Answer (score 1):

That **preserving duplicates** got my head but finally got a solution

```
a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]
c=[]
def dublicate_finder(a,b):
    global c
    if len(a)>len(b):
        for i in range(len(b)):
            if b[i] in a:
                c.append(b[i])
                remove_index=a.index(b[i],0,len(a))
                del a[remove_index]
    if len(a)>len(b):
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] in b:
                c.append(a[i])
                remove_index=b.index(a[i],0,len(b))
                del a[remove_index]
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use the `any` operator to check if the element is equal to that in other list.

Then remove the element

```
a = [1,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [3,5,5,5,6]
l3=[]
for  i in b:
    if any(i==j for j in a):
        l3.append(i)
        a.remove(i)
        
print(l3)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't scale well when the lists are large. It's O(len(a)*len(b)) while the optimal solution is O(len(a)+len(b)).

Comment: Also, note that if there is no copy of `a`, the lists at the beginning and the end are not the same.

Answer (score -3):

Although `set.intersection` removes duplicates, it can be very useful nonetheless:

```
a_set = set(a)
b_set = set(b)

intr = a_set.intersection(set_b)

result = [element for element in a if element in intr]
```

That should work

Comment: This doesn't count them properly. If you swap `a` and `b` it will return `5` four times not two.

Comment: that corresponds to the example he attached

Comment: @JohnKugelman ok, i didnt understand the problem